# Is there a built-in semaphore structure that allows for waiting on more than one resource?

Tags: c, semaphore

I would like to be able wait/post more than one resource at a time. Is there a built-in c structure and interface that allows for this?

Currently I am using `semaphore.h` however this interface has the limitation that it can only request a single resource at a time.

I could do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < resources; i++)
    sem_wait(my_sem);
```

But this would be time consuming if `resources` is large and I would also need to add another lock before this so that I am guaranteed that the requester has priority over other threads that may be requesting resources.
It would end up looking something like this:

```
sem_wait(my_lock);
for (int i = 0; i < resources; i++)
    sem_wait(my_sem);
sem_post(my_lock);
```

not to mention extra error checks that would need to happen.

What I would like to be able to do is something like this:

```
sem_wait(my_lock, resources);
```

This would simply wait until all resources are available and then return after decrementing the semaphore by the requested number of resources. I feel like I've seen something like this a while back but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Depending on how often and how long you're locking for you could use a [spinlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock) with atomic variables, presumably.

Comment: This will be used as part of a pipeline so there isn't an limit on how long I might be waiting

Comment: Semaphores are just one way to coordinate, you could also use mutexes. In any case, you need to wait for all of those semaphores to flip, so waiting in parallel or waiting in series has no change on the outcome. Either they're all clear or there's a block.

Comment: "waiting in parallel or waiting in series has no change on the outcome" that depends on what type of resource the semaphore is synchronizing. For my purposes the outcome would change and waiting in parallel is simply not an option. I need the resources to be allocated to threads in a contiguous manner. waiting for individual resources in parallel with other threads would provide sparsely located resources. If there isn't anything built-in that is fine, I just thought I remembered using something like this a while back but couldn't find anything so I thought I would reach out here to check.

Comment: The biggest problem with serially acquiring the semaphore multiple times is not how time consuming it might be, but rather a pretty significant deadlock risk.  Suppose there are six resources total, and two threads are each trying to acquire four of them.  If they manage to acquire three each at the same time, then neither will ever be able to proceed.  The resource acquisition needs to be atomic in order to avoid this kind of problem.

Comment: If it's sequenced, then great, that makes your life easier. You just grab one after the next and release when they're no longer required. This question read, initially, that you needed to grab *N* semaphores in any particular order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are presently using POSIX semaphores.  They do not directly afford the possibility of atomically changing the semaphore value by more than one, except when creating a new semaphore.

System V semaphores (`semget` / `semctl` / `semop`) are generally considered inferior, but they do have some features that the POSIX flavor lacks, and this is one of them.  Specifically, you can use `semop()` to *atomically* deduct any positive number from the semaphore's value, blocking until this can be done without reducing the value below zero.

But System V IPC is enough of a pain overall that I'd suggest instead setting up a shared variable representing the number of resources presently available, and using a mutex + condition variable instead of a semaphore.  That would look something like this:

```
unsigned resources_available = ALL_RESOURCES;
pthread_mutex_t resource_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t resource_cv = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

// ...

int acquire_resources(unsigned resources_wanted) {
    int result;

    // ...

    result = pthread_mutex_lock(resource_mutex);
    // handle errors ...
    while (resources_available < resources_wanted) {
        result = pthread_cond_wait(resource_cv, resource_mutex);
        // handle errors ...
    }
    resources_available -= resources_wanted;
    result = pthread_mutex_unlock(resource_mutex);
    // ...
}

int release_resources(unsigned resources_released) {
    int result;

    // ...

    result = pthread_mutex_lock(resource_mutex);
    // handle errors ...
    resources_available += resources_released;
    result = pthread_cond_broadcast(resource_cv);
    // handle errors ...
    result = pthread_mutex_unlock(resource_mutex);
    // ...
}
```